# Do moderator tools work on an iPad?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

OK, I am still trying to get a handle on how the moderator tools work, but I had a problem tonight.

I attempted to handle a flag tonight via my iPad.  The option to convert an answer to a comment wasn't enabled, and when I tried to go back into the list of flags, all options on on that flag were disabled.

I am not sure if this was because I was using an iPad, or if it was pilot error on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option to convert an answer to a comment is disabled, when there are comments for the answer. What you can do in that case is going to the question page, and select the option to convert the answer to comment from there.

I cannot comment on the options for a flag not being enabled, as I have never had such issue, even using my iPod.

Comment: Thanks.  I see how to handle that case now.